# ASP.net 5 Identites , not everywhere authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

After signing a user in with the following code, i can see that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true. Also the UserName ist set.

```
  var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vm.UserName, vm.Password, vm.RememberMe, false);
```

But Identity in other apis are not set

```
var ident2 = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
var ident3 = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
```

They are all **not** authenticated. Is this as expected in a asp.net 5 application?

Answer (score 1):

When you sign someone in and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true then this means that the `HttpContext.User.Identity` is set to the logged in user.

`Thread.CurrentPrinciple` will return the worker process user that is being used to host the application.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this as expected in a asp.net 5 application?

Yes it is, since neither `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` nor `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` (used internally by `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` by default) are set by ASP.NET 5. To retrieve the user associated with the current request, your only option is to use `HttpContext.User` (which is not static).

It may change in the future, though: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/322.